# Dynamically capture values after pivot transform in Vega-Lite

Tags: javascript, vega, vega-lite

In this example: https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/interactive_multi_line_pivot_tooltip.html

They use a pivot transform & then statically write down each value for the field `symbol` as a tooltip field.

```
   "tooltip": [
          {"field": "AAPL", "type": "quantitative"},
          {"field": "AMZN", "type": "quantitative"},
          {"field": "GOOG", "type": "quantitative"},
          {"field": "IBM", "type": "quantitative"},
          {"field": "MSFT", "type": "quantitative"}
        ]
```

Say i didn't know the actual values in my dataset, how would i dynamically generate the same tooltip?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this by removing the explicit tooltip encoding and setting the mark property as

```
"mark": {"type": "rule", "tooltip": {"content": "data"}}
```

(see [docs](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/tooltip.html#data)), but there appears to be a [bug](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/6260) in this behavior, so it doesn't work as of Vega-Lite 4.9.

The only workaround I'm aware of for the time being is to specify the tooltip values explicitly.

Comment: Here's a working example with your code, added to the chart from the question: https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/fa4b7ada1febf1e312b5f58421272ac1/Stock%20charts%20with%20dynamic%20tooltip.json